# Loss of Incrdible credits while build the App in Server

Tags: ios, codenameone

Am losing nearly 20-40 credits for each build of an ios debug build in codename one.. is it normal.

And finally i end up with 0 build credits within 2-3 builds.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I build to all devices for free? Yes. Up to 100 credits per month with an iOS build taking up 20 credits due to the cost of running Mac servers in the cloud and the longer build times.

Source: http://www.codenameone.com/faq.html